# How to detect if a region of the image is empty? or How to detect the presence of a character or number in a squared image?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0, mnist

I have been working on MNIST dataset recognition for Sudoku. The sudoku puzzle contains both empty and non-empty boxes (9x9). 
[Before and after applying perspective transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIMRM.png)

Now, I have extracted each square of the sudoku as below:
[Extracted squares from sudoku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7DtG.png)

How do I apply MNIST data recognition model for only the blobs with numbers? 
How do I check if a digit is potentially present in the blob, so that MNIST can be applied to only those blobs?

Comment: You could calculate variance of pixel values in the square. Non-empty squares should have larger variance in values than empty squares.

Comment: Hi, I am working with images of size 28x28, so the variance lies in a narrow bandwidth from 8000-12000 for both cases(with and without numbers). I can't decide a conducive variance, which will work for other images as well. 
Is there any other way in opencv to go around this ?

Comment: You need to remove the square edges before computing the variance.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Variance for a smaller portion of the image that doesn't include the square edges works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of pixels inside the square in the central region and use certain threshold to count the white pixels, white pixel count can be used as a parameter to classify empty or non empty square.
This may fail in some cases with salt noise in the central region of square, you can remove them using median filter before counting the white pixels in the central region.

I have a given an example for the above logic

Assuming you have extracted square of shape (28X28)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
square = np.random.rand(28,28) #this is the extracted square region
#crop the central square region to ignore the square edges 
central_square = square[5:-5,5:-5]
denoised_square = ndimage.median_filter(central_square, 3)
#count the white pixels
white_pix_count = np.count_nonzero(denoised_square)
if white_pix_count > thresh:
   empty_square = False
else:
   empty_square = True
```

Comment: This works too. But Please do checkout the method suggested by @sebasth in the first comment for the question, in which i don't have to import any additional modules.